# Sympy cancelling terms in the Jacobian of polar coordinates transformation

Tags: trigonometry, sympy

I am preparing examples of how a Jacobian is arrived at using transformations from polar/cartesian parametrisations. My question is twofold. First, I want to know how to force sympy to cancel out terms following substitution. 
The two matrices are:

```
J1 = Matrix([[(r*cos(theta)).diff(r), (r*cos(theta)).diff(theta)],[(r*sin(theta)).diff(r),(r*sin(theta)).diff(theta)]])
J2 = Matrix([[((x**2+y**2)**(1/2.)).diff(x),((x**2+y**2)**(1/2.)).diff(y)],[atan(y/x).diff(x),atan(y/x).diff(y)]])
#substitute for x,y to have same variables for J1 and J2
J2 = trigsimp(J2.subs({x:r*cos(theta), y:r*sin(theta)}))
J2
```

I expected that using cancel(), or even evalf() would have removed the r/(r^2)^1/2= 1 term, but it did not.

Second, how or can one require sympy to recognise simple identities, in this case sin^2+cos^2 = 1? This is so that the result is an evaluated identity matrix from J1*J2.

This works, as per documentation:

```
simplify(r/(r**2)**(1/2)*(sin(theta)**2+cos(theta)**2))
```

This equivalent(ish) equation does not.

```
J = J1*J2
simplify(J[0,0])
```

It seems that the second error is a consequence of the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically, r/(r^2)^1/2= 1 is not always true. It's true if r is a nonnegative number, which it is in polar coordinates. So you should tell SymPy this:

```
r = Symbol('r', nonnegative=True) 
theta, x, y = symbols('theta x y')
```

(Mathematically, you can even assume r strictly positive, `positive=True`, since at the origin derivatives in polar coordinates don't work anyway.)

The output will be much more agreeable: `[[1.0*cos(theta), 1.0*sin(theta)], [-sin(theta)/r, cos(theta)/r]]`

Only this 1.0 is annoying, where does it come from? It comes from 1/2. being a float instead of a rational number. Use `Rational(1, 2)` to have a rational number in the exponent (important for simplification). In this case, the exponent being 1/2, it's more natural to use `sqrt` which has the same effect of making the exponent rational and is easier to type.

```
sqrt(x**2+y**2).diff(x)
```

The end result is `[[cos(theta), sin(theta)], [-sin(theta)/r, cos(theta)/r]]`

As for trigonometric simplification, `trigsimp(J1*J2)` does return the identity matrix.

Comment: I have the same question but instead of r/(r**2)**(1/2), I have cos(x)/(cos(x)**2)**(1/2), which is true for my domain of -pi/2 < x < pi/2. How can I then simplify my expression?